# How can we find duplicate code using Netbeans similar to Intellij?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, code-duplication, netbeans-plugins

There is lots of duplicates codes including:

```
Duplicates within file
Duplicates within package
Duplicates around multiple packages
Duplicates around separate Maven Modules
```

Is there any way to find duplicate codes using Netbeans 8+ or Netbeans Plugins or Maven Plugin with Netbeans or Standalone tools similar to Intellij?

I am unable to find documentation of same.

I have found PMD in Maven but unable to link with Netbeans 8.2 and We are only supposed to use Netbeans

Comment: This may be where you want to consider downloading intellij.

Comment: @CloneTalk: But we are suppose to use Netbeans only

Comment: Yes, but maybe the tools are the limiting factor and it is time to switch over so that you can improve your productivity. Also you could do that thing where they both have the same project location so you get the best of both worlds.

Comment: There is no plugin/integration for any modern Netbeans version. Just use standalone PMD (launch `cpdgui.bat`) or IntelliJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find duplicated code for a NetBeans Maven project using the [Apache Maven PMD Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-pmd-plugin). Simply add the following to your project's **pom.xml**:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                        <goal>cpd-check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

When you build your project PMD's copy paste detector (CPD) will be run, and write its results to file **{project directory}\target\cpd.xml**. If no duplication is found that file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmd-cpd>
</pmd-cpd>
```

However, if duplication is found the file looks similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmd-cpd>
<duplication lines="162" tokens="608">
<file line="95" path="D:\NetBeansProjectsJava9\checkduplication\src\main\java\com\unthreading\checkduplication\ParseJavadoc.java"/>
<file line="258" path="D:\NetBeansProjectsJava9\checkduplication\src\main\java\com\unthreading\checkduplication\ParseJavadoc.java"/>
<codefragment>
<![CDATA[

    ...details of the duplicated code....

]]>
</codefragment>
</duplication>
</pmd-cpd>
```

After updating the POM as described above, a very simple way to verify that duplication detection is working is to copy/paste a large method within some class, and then give the pasted method another name so that the code still compiles. I tried that and got the following result in the **Output** window:

> maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1:cpd-check (default) @ checkduplication ---
>
> BUILD FAILURE
>
> Total time: 2.689 s Finished at: 2018-02-15T17:06:23-05:00 Final
>   Memory: 20M/70M
>
> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-pmd-plugin:2.7.1:cpd-check (default) on
>   project checkduplication: You have 1 CPD duplication. For more details
>   see:D:\NetBeansProjectsJava9\checkduplication\target\cpd.xml -> [Help
>   1]

A couple of final points:

- Specifying `<goal>cpd-check</goal>` (as I did) causes the build to fail when duplication is detected, but [alternative goals can be specified](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/plugin-info.html).
- There are more recent versions of **maven-pmd-plugin** than **2.7.1**, but that is the most recent version where copy/paste detection works out of the box. More recent versions may work after playing with the configuration, but I didn't try that.